# Bullet proof way to get string to test encoding

Tags: android, utf-8

I am having utf-8 encoding trouble and was looking for a way to create a test string that was known to contain at least one utf-8 character. Ideally I would like to have a string contain a lower-case e with an acute. This is unicode 00e9 which should be encoded as a byte C3 followed by a second byte A9.

Imagine that I can not guarantee that the encoding in my editor is correct - so I guess I need to somehow create a byte array and covert to a string?? Not sure - please advise.

I want the string for loading into a webview like so:

```
webView.loadData(test_string, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: "Imagine that I can not guarantee that the encoding in my editor is correct" Why not? All good, modern text editors will save as a specific encoding, and can convert characters between encodings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode unicode by using the \u escape. Since ICS loadData does not seem to work with encoded strings, use loadDataWithBaseURL passing null for first and last params:

```
String test_string="One e and another type \u00E9";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, test_string, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```